# str_replace_all is replacing character which was replaced already

Tags: r, str-replace

I am testing `str_replace_all` function in `stringr` package. Please see the code below.

```
library(stringr) 
originalString<-c("d", "a", "c")
patternColor=c("coral", "burlywood1", "darkkhaki")
names(patternColor)<-originalString
subsetColNameChar<-c("d", "d", "a", "a", "c", "c")
replaceOut<-str_replace_all(subsetColNameChar, patternColor)
replaceOut
[1] "darkkhakiorburlywood1l" "darkkhakiorburlywood1l" "burlywood1" "burlywood1"  "darkkhaki"  "darkkhaki"
```

The expected output should be:

```
[1] "coral" "coral" "burlywood1" "burlywood1" "darkkhaki" "darkkhaki"
```

But, as you see its output above, It is replacing "c" and "a" in "coral" with "darkkhaki" and "burlywood1" again. (If you see it carefully, still there are "or" and "l" left). If I use just number in `originalString<-c("1","2","3")`, I could get the correct replacement as I expect. But, I don't know why `str_replace_all` is replacing "c" and "a" in "coral" again, which are already replaced. What can be a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: From str_replace's documentation: "To perform multiple replacements in each element of string, pass a named vector (c(pattern1 = replacement1)) to str_replace_all.". In other words, you need to have an unnamed pattern vector and an unnamed replacement vector in `str_replace`

Comment: You have to check how the function works. Try those two versions `str_replace_all(subsetColNameChar, c("c"="darkkhaki", "a"="burlywood1", "d"="coral"))` and `str_replace_all(subsetColNameChar, c("d"="coral", "a"="burlywood1", "c"="darkkhaki"))` and you'll see that it works in a sequence. That's why some patterns get replaced again.

Comment: iod, thank you for your explanation. You are right. I passed named pattern vector because I wanted to perform multiple replacement by str_replace_all.

Comment: AntoniosK, thank you for your answer. I ran two versions you gave, and understood better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.replace` is vectorized over string, pattern, and replacement. Meaning, it searches for the first pattern in the first string, and if it finds it, applies the first replacement, then moves on to the second string, looks for the second pattern (only), and if it finds it, applies the second replacement, etc.

When you pass a named vector as the pattern to `str.replace.all`, it loops the entire pattern vector over each string element, giving you the result you saw.

One alternative you might consider is `qdap::multigsub`, which does basically what the name says: multiple gsub grep-and-replaces:

```
multigsub(originalString, patternColor, subsetColNameChar)
```

Comment: Thanks to you, I understood that str_replace_all loops the entire pattern vector over each string element.  By the way, I tested your code, 'multigsub' function, but it still doesn't work;                                                                          
                                                                               
                          
    [5] "coralburlywoocoral1rkkhburlywoocoral1ki"
    [6] "coralburlywoocoral1rkkhburlywoocoral1ki"

Comment: Hmm... Yes, I see. I guess it really depends on what your trying to achieve. For example, would it be possible to replace the patterns vector with something like `c("^a$", "^b$")`, so that it matches only full strings?

Comment: Oh, I got it.  I put the names like  originalString<-c("^d$", "^a$", "^c$"), and it worked.  Thank you, iod!  I learned a new thing.